# How to access a dynamically created DOM element in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-dom, use-ref

This is something similar to what i have excluding any others divs:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Post({post}) {

<div className="postDesc">
    {post.sanitizedHtml} //This contains p tag inside
</div>

    )
}
```

This post prop is coming from an api and post.sanitizedHtml basically contains raw html that has tags such as p ,h2 etc.

What i want is to **access the p tag that is inside post.sanitizedHtml** so that i can use the javascript property .textContent on it and extract the information.

But i think there is no method in react like **document.querySelector or document.getElementBy:Id/Classname**

Also i think i can't use refs because the data is coming in dynamically and i cant write ref={something} as a prop

So what should i do to access the p tag that is there inside the **post.sanitizedHtml** ?

Your fast response is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` ?

Comment: @HarshitRastogi I think that is just going to render the whole html which i have done on the other pages of the website but I just want the p tags how can i access it?

Comment: @Saswat you can set a ref on the outer div, and access its child nodes. This obviously means you'd have to know beforehand what you want to access inside the dynamic html.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekSharma for your wonderful suggestion. I was thinking of something like that. If you can modify my code and post this as an answer to how can i exactly access the child nodes on the div it would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting a ref on the outer div, you can access its child nodes and change their properties as you like.

[Read more about Child Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export const Post = ({post}) => {
  
  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  
  //Let's Change something inside the post
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!post.sanitizedHtml || !containerRef.current) return;
    
    const container = containerRef.current;
    const childNodes = container.childNodes; //This will be a list of child nodes
    /* let's say 0th element of childNodes is a p tag */
    childNodes[0].innerText = "Hey I changed Something";
    
    
  }, [post, containerRef])
  
  return(
    <div className="postDesc" ref={containerRef}>
      {post.sanitizedHtml}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, are you able to create an element with javascript and assign the sanitizedHtml to it, then just reference it from the newly created element?

```
const myElement = document.createElement("DIV"); 
myElement.innerHTML = post.santizedHtml;

then lookup from myElement
```